# Git clone failed while unpacking - lack of space - how to recover without a full clone?

Tags: git

I cloned a repo with git yesterday and ran out of space on my VMs HDD. I've since moved the repo and have enough space. `git clone` ran out of space during unpacking the downloaded objects. The thing is, git thinks it's up to date, but `git status` lists pages of deleted files.

Git pull doesn't work as it thinks it's up to date. What can I do so I don't have to clone the entire repository again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

This should update your working copy.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** Sry, I misread and thought the object database might have been corrupt/incomplete.

---

don't. However, if you insist you might get somewhere with `git fsck` or if you're really desperate for bandwidth: `rsync`

```
rsync -hxPavilyzH --delete user@remote:/repo/origin/.git/ brokenclone/.git/
```

To find out what speed up / bandwidth optimization to expect:

```
rsync -hxPavilyzH --delete user@remote:/repo/origin/.git/ brokenclone/.git/ -n --stats
```